# Does one 'do' or 'perform' a code review?

Tags: phrase-request

In software development, a code review is a process when one developer inspects a code written by another developer to find possible mistakes or to suggest improvements.

Which of these is correct (if any)?

> - to **do** a code review
> - to **perform** a code review

Comment: 'Perform' is more formal, 'do', less so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spoken language, I'd vote for both the phrases.

> Did you *do* a code review? 
>  Did you *perform* a code review?

Nevertheless, there's another version:

> Did you *review* the code?

So, to answer, as far as *correct* phrase is concerned, in spoken language, the context defined, both are *okay.*